# How to turn firefox in an analysis tool for predefined MIME-types?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How can one modify firefox to analyze some file formats by an external program?

For example i wan't to analyze any GIF image that is loaded while browsing.
I'd like to do this using an external script i've written.

I know that it would be easier to program some kind of crawler, but i'd like to analyze files while browsing and at the time they're loaded.

Comment: What is this script written in? I'm thinking you can do a copule things. Open your script via command line and get the return value. Or use js-ctypes to access it the script, run it, and return the value.

Comment: My question is more about how to process incoming data before it gets rendered by firefox. For example how do i process a loading image with an external program before it shows up.

Comment: It's ok if the data is processed _after_ rendering _too_. But i'd like to avoid that the data is loaded twice. So maybe i can access the loaded files in cache or something?

Comment: oh i see ill write my thoughts in a solution

Answer (score 0):

Thinkng out loud: I can use nsITraceableChannel to get a copy of whats rendering, but I don't know how to get it before render.

Possible solution, no code: The one way to  Well I can use `http-on-modify-request` observer to figure out the uri of what they are requesting. Then I can pause the request. Then do a xmlhttprequest to get that data. Send it to your thing and do whatever. Then rather than unapuse the request, feed it the data you had (so you avoid double request).